# Is there a way to create an unordered html list from an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, haml

I want to use pure html and javascript instead of HAML.
Before when I was working with this form project I loop through the array like this

```
- @item1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
- item1.each_with_index do |item, i|
   %li.option
      %input.option-input{name: 'options', type: 'radio', value: i, id: "options-#{i}"}/
      %label.option-label{:for => "options-#{i}"}= item1
```

Comment: You need to give us more information. You want to create an unordered what? Where exactly is the issue, and what is the question? Please be more explicit.

Comment: lol the title sound like you want to actively scramble the array before passing it to html :d

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    (function(){
        const items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
        const ul = document.createElement('UL');
        for (let i=0; i< items.length; i++){
            const item = items[i];
            const li = document.createElement('LI');
            const label = document.createElement('LABEL');
            const input = document.createElement('INPUT');
            input.value = item;
            input.setAttribute('id', 'options-' + i);
            input.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
            input.setAttribute('name', 'options');
            label.appendChild(input);
            label.setAttribute('for', 'options-' + i);
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
            li.appendChild(label);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(ul);
    })();
</script>
```